# Searching for Windows Explorer like UI component

Tags: c#, .net, components

Hallo,

atm we're searching for a UI component for browsing files and folders. Since now we have used the File Browser at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/FileBrowser.aspx, but because we're facing many problems (access violations and other exceptions) we need a more stable one.

Do you know any with the following features:

- Stable!
- It would be nice if it is widely used and well-proven.
- Must be able to programmatically filter the files by extension.
- Preferably open source or for free, but it doesn't absolutely need to.

Thanks in advance,

Steven

Comment: Which technology are you using WPF? Silverlight? WinForms? ASP.NET?

Comment: Currently we need Windows Forms, but in the long-term future we'll migrate to WPF.

Answer (score 1):

What about this [FileView Control](http://www.ssware.com/fileview/fileview.htm)?

[image]